# AngularJS xeditable number field with float validation

Tags: html, angularjs

I have issue with AngularJS.
If I use xeditable

```
<a editable-number="some.object"....
```

I can't input float numbers... 
So, how can I add float numbers and have float validation in view ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set the `step` attribute of the `<input type="number">` tag to "any".

One way to solve this is to take advantage of xeditable's `e-*` syntax, where any attribute you specify that begins with `e-` will be passed through to the underlying input tag:

```
<a editable-number="some.object" e-step="any">{{some.object || 'Enter Number'}}</a>
```