# AngularJS x-editable Locale-based decimal separator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, locale, x-editable

I'm not able to make xeditable work with localized decimal numbers.

I have searched both in the official documentation and online in other forums/websites but I wasn't able to get any clue.

The only similar issue was this SO question: [AngularJS xeditable number field with float validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731063/angularjs-xeditable-number-field-with-float-validation)

To sum up the problem: I would like to use a comma instead of a dot as a decimal separator but x-editable automatically transform the separator in a dot when I go into "edit mode". **How can I deal with localization for decimal numbers?**

Here is the code

```
<span e-form="rowform" e-name="value.value" editable-text="property.value.value" onbeforesave="checkIsNumeric($data)">
    {property.value.value || 'empty'}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a locale file like described in the [angular i18n documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)? You should pick one of your language that already contains a comma. Otherwise theoretically you could manipulate your locale file and add a comma as decimal separator. The different locale files (angular 1.4.7) can be downloaded [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/i18n/) for example.