# How to allow editable-number to decimal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, x-editable

hi all i am using angularjs editable-number it's only allow number to enter but my need is it's allows decimal also it's not allow to enter decimal values help how to solve this problem

```
<a href="#" editable-number="user.number"></a>
```

Comment: try to use `e-step="any"`. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731063/angularjs-xeditable-number-field-with-float-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `e-step` attribute to `"any"`:

```
<a href="#" editable-number="user.number" e-step="any">{{user.number || 'Enter number'}}</a>
```

Comment: thanks yar it's working

Comment: @jose It will be nice of you to accept the answer then ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118393/auto-checked-enabled-in-angularjs

Comment: help to solve this pblm

Comment: editable-text to be required it's possible.empty should not be allowed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209640/inside-ng-click-get-function-not-working-in-angularjs-mongoose

Comment: help what is the issuse